# MySQL CREATE TABLE FROM VIEW with PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL view:

[image]

And am trying to write an SQL script to create a table populated with data from the view while assigning a primary key.

Comment: Why do you want to copy data from one table to another? That's asking for data inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to accomplish this using a script similar to that below:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp_div_numprojects`(
`dn_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`dn_id`), KEY(`managing_division`))
SELECT
`managing_division` AS `managing_division`,
COUNT(DISTINCT `project_id`) AS `number_of_projects`
FROM
    `report_view`
GROUP BY
    `managing_division`
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]